# How to unit test a computed property in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, computed-properties, guard-statement

How can I unit test the guard statement of a computed property in swift?

When the unit tests are run, the `fataError` line is not included in the code coverage.

Is there any way to test the computed properties?

```
class HomePresenter: HomeViewToPresenterProtocol {

    var view: HomePresenterToViewProtocol?
    var router: HomePresenterToRouterProtocol?
    var interactor: HomePresentorToInterectorProtocol?

    var homeView: UIViewController {
        guard let view = view as? UIViewController else {
            fatalError("View cannot be casted as UIViewController")
        }
        return view
    }

    init(view: HomePresenterToViewProtocol, interactor: HomePresentorToInterectorProtocol, router: HomePresenterToRouterProtocol) {
        self.view = view
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.router = router
    }
```

}

Comment: Should you really use fatalError in production code?

Comment: I cannot?  I thought it is a good practice to use fatalError.

Comment: Well it will crash your app, is this really what you want and do you think it will be a good user experience when the app just crashes without any message or information explaining why.

Comment: yes, I know the app will crash if the runtime hits that code. But it is not likely to happen because the casting will always succeed.

Comment: Do you really need to bother with a unit test then? In generar you can always use fail, `XCTFail()`, to force the test to fail if it continues after a code row

Comment: You would achieve the same effect much more easily by `return view as! UIViewController`.